# How to enlarge toolbar size in Qt?

Tags: qt, toolbar

I have a Qt window with a toolbar. I have several actions in it, with their icons set to some of qt standard icons.

However, they are rather small. I want to enlarge toolbar and the buttons inside, so that their icons would stretch accordingly. How should i go about it?

As of now, toolbar was filled using QtCreatir's designer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add a stylesheet. There are several ways to do that (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html). I use an external stylesheet and increase the toolbar size with following code:

```
    QToolButton
    {
        height: 64px;
        width: 64px;
    }
```